# SQL Server stored procedure calling from another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000, from one stored procedure (`Master` stored procedure) I am calling a series of other procedures.

The nth procedure is throwing a `column not found` error, but the nth procedure got executed just fine if I run it separately.

If I place this nth procedure at any place in the `master` stored procedure it behaves in the same way.

Can anyone please help me to find solution to this problem?

Comment: Would you be willing to share the code of the nth procedure and the part of the master procedure calling it with us? This really does not give us much to go on...

Comment: Looks like somewhere in the master procedure, you are manipulating the data returned from the nth procedure and thus, selecting an incorrect column name. Debug your master procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure is doing any type of DDL against a table, the same transaction cannot correctly reference the table.  For example, if you have a stored procedure that runs a SELECT... INTO and then another statement that runs an ALTER TABLE... ADD columns, you will run into this issue.